# Setting VoiceOver focus order on current collectionView page

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, accessibility, voiceover

I am trying to add full VoiceOver support to my app. I have a calendar that's a `collectionView` where the current date is in one of the middle pages. When using the one-finger swipe in VoiceOver to change the speaker focus, it automatically goes to the first page of the collectionView.

**How can I have VoiceOver's focus automatically go to the current page instead of the first?**

I know that `accessibilityElements` can set the order of VoiceOver's focus, but I cannot figure out how to have it start at the correct index. Please let me know if you know anything or if this is the right method. I really appreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: Inside the cellForRowAt, try doing `cell.isAccessibilityElement = true`

Comment: cell.dateLabel.isAccessibilityElement = true
 self.accessibilityElements = [cell.dateLabel]
self.accessibilityElements?.append(cell.dateLabel)